# Write a Lex rule to parse Integer and Float

Tags: parsing, lex

I am writing a parse for a script language.

I need to recognize `strings`, `integers` and `floats`.

I successfully recognize strings with the rule:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_]+ {return STRING;}
```

But I have problem recognizing Integers and Floats. These are the (wrong) rules I wrote:

```
["+"|"-"][1-9]{DIGIT}*  { return INTEGER;}
["+"|"-"]["0." | [1-9]{DIGIT}*"."]{DIGIT}+ {return FLOAT;}
```

How can I fix them?

Furthermore, since a "*abc123*" is a valid string, how can I make sure that it is recognized as a string and not as the concatenation of a string ("`abc`") and an Integer ("`123`") ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem: There's a difference between `(...)` and `[...]`. Your regular expressions don't do what you think they do because you're using the wrong punctuation.

Beyond that:

1. No numeric rule recognizes `0`.
2. Both numeric rules require an explicit sign.
3. Your STRING rule recognizes integers.

So, to start:

`[...]` encloses a *set* of individual characters or character ranges. It matches a *single character* which is a member of the set.

`(...)` encloses a regular expression. The parentheses are used for grouping, as in mathematics.

`"..."` encloses a *sequence* of individual characters, and matches exactly those characters.

With that in mind, let's look at

```
["+"|"-"][1-9]{DIGIT}*
```

The first bracket expression `["+"|"-"]` is a set of individual characters or ranges. In this case, the set contains: <kbd>"</kbd>, <kbd>+</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> (again, which has no effect because a set contains zero or one instances of each member), <kbd>|</kbd>, and the range <kbd>"</kbd>-<kbd>"</kbd>, which is a range whose endpoints are the same character, and consequently only includes that character, <kbd>"</kbd>, which is already in the set. In short, that was equivalent to `["+|]`. It will match one of those three characters. It requires one of those three characters, in fact.

The second bracket expression `[1-9]` matches one character in the range <kbd>1</kbd>-<kbd>9</kbd>, so it probably does what you expected. Again, it matches exactly one character.

Finally, `{DIGIT}` matches the expansion of the name `DIGIT`. I'll assume that you have the definition:

```
DIGIT   [0-9]
```

somewhere in your definitions section. (In passing, I note that you could have just used the character class `[:digit:]`, which would have been unambiguous, and you would not have needed to define it.) It's followed by a `*`, which means that it will match zero or more repetitions of the `{DIGIT}` definition.

Now, an example of a string which matches that pattern:

```
|42
```

And some examples of strings which don't match that pattern:

```
-7   # The pattern must start with |, + or "
42   # Again, the pattern must start with |, + or "
+0   # The character following the + must be in the range [0-9]
```

Similarly, your float pattern, once the `[...]` expressions are simplified, becomes (writing out the individual pieces one per line, to make it more obvious):

```
["+|]      # i.e. the set " + |
["0.|[1-9] # i.e. the set " 0 | [ 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
{DIGIT}*   # Any number of digits
"."        # A single period
]          # A single ]
{DIGIT}+   # one or more digits
```

So here's a possible match:

```
"..]3
```

I'll skip over writing out the solution because I think you'll benefit more from doing it yourself.

Now, the other issues:

1. Some rule should match `0`. If you don't want to allow leading zeros, you'll need to just a it as a separate rule.
2. Use the optional operator (`?`) to indicate that the preceding object is optional. eg. `"foo"?` matches either the three characters <kbd>f</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd> (in order) or matches the empty string. You can use that to make the sign optional.
3. The problem is not the matching of `abc123`, as in your question. (F)lex always gives you the longest possible match, and the only rule which could match the starting character `a` is the string rule, so it will allow the string rule to continue as long as it can. It will always match all of `abc123`. However, it will also match `123`, which you would probably prefer to be matched by your numeric rule. Here, the other (f)lex matching criterion comes into play: when there are two or more rules which could match exactly the same string, and none of the rules can match a longer string, (f)lex chooses the *first rule* in the file. So if you want to give numbers priority over strings, you have to put the number rule earlier in your (f)lex file than the string rule.

I hope that gives you some ideas about how to fix things.